# repr() on Tree node causing infinite recursion

Tags: python

Here I have an attempt for implenenting a printable tree:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, child=[]):
        self.value = value
        self.child = child
    def __repr__(self):
        print('Debug:', self.value)
        valuestr = repr(self.value)
        childstr = ', '.join([repr(x) for x in self.child])
        return "Node({0}, [{1}])".format(valuestr, childstr)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()
```

When I run the following code, it works as expected.

```
A=Node('A')
B=Node('B')
C=Node('C')
A.child=[B, C]
print(A)

# Output:
# Debug: A
# Debug: B
# Debug: C
# Node('A', [Node('B', []), Node('C' [])])
```

But, when `A.child.append(B)` is used instead of `A.child=[B, C]`, it causes an infinite recursion.

```
Debug: A
Debug: B
Debug: B
Debug: B
...
Debug: B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts3/.last_tmp.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(A)
  File "/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts3/.last_tmp.py", line 15, in __str__
    return self.__repr__()
  File "/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts3/.last_tmp.py", line 12, in __repr__
    childstr = ', '.join([repr(x) for x in self.child])
  File "/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts3/.last_tmp.py", line 12, in <listcomp>
    childstr = ', '.join([repr(x) for x in self.child])
  File "/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts3/.last_tmp.py", line 12, in __repr__
    childstr = ', '.join([repr(x) for x in self.child])
...
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

And, in case of the following,

```
A=Node('A')
B=Node('B')
C=Node('C')
A.child.append(B)
print(C)
```

The same error occurs again; But with `Debug: C` instead of `Debug: A` in the first line.

What is causing this behaviour? Why is **repr**() acting strangely when nodes are appended to the list of children, not assigned?

Currently using Python 3.2.7, qpython for Android.

Comment: Your problem is known as "mutable default argument"

Comment: Not related to your issue, but helpful if your graph can have cycles: https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html#reprlib.recursive_repr